# VHDL: enumeration types in entities of submodules?

Tags: vhdl

I have a top level module and an enumeration type declared there. Now I created several submodules (with an IN port of the that type) and instantiated them. However, resolving the enumeration type in submodules fails.
Is it possible to reuse the enumeration type and if, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a package and include that package at the top of each module.

Here is an example of a package:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package my_package is

    type type_enumexample is (left, right, top, bottom);

end my_package;

package body my_package is

end my_package;
```

To include it in each module just add this where you have your other use statements:

```
-- The package is compiled to this directory by default.
-- so don't forget to include this directory. 
library work;
-- This includes the particular package into your program.
use work.my_package.all;
```

Every module you include the package on, you can use your custom enum type.